# Out of Memory during doinbackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, out-of-memory

I have the following code:-

```
public class ByState extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.by_state, container, false);
        new GetAllStates().execute("dummy");
        return rootView;
    }
}
class GetAllStates extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... key) {
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            String url = "http://congress-search-148802.appspot.com/getData.php?value=legislator";
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String groupResponse) {
        Log.d("My message",groupResponse);
        try {
            JSONArray groupList = new JSONArray(groupResponse);
            for(int i=0;i<groupList.length();i++){
                JSONObject groupInfo = groupList.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("BioguideID ",groupInfo.getString("bioguide_id"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not doing much but still I am getting the following error:-

```
1-15 00:05:02.793 27120-27157/com.app.congress.congressapp E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 203542 byte allocation with 150292 free bytes and 146KB until OOM"
11-15 00:05:02.803 27120-27157/com.app.congress.congressapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.app.congress.congressapp, PID: 27120
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 203542 byte allocation with 150292 free bytes and 146KB until OOM
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:271)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:414)
        at com.app.congress.congressapp.GetAllStates.doInBackground(ByState.java:46)
        at com.app.congress.congressapp.GetAllStates.doInBackground(ByState.java:34)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have tried to increase the heap to large heap which is not recommended but still I get this error. Am pretty new to this can some one point out where I am going wrong??

Comment: are you using device or AVD?

Comment: Do you need to work on the full response ? Can't you use a file

Comment: I am using AVD currently.

Comment: Yes I need the full response to display in a list view

Comment: `StringBuffer` is cousing error. It is expensive task. Try searching for alternatives

Comment: try to test on real device, also if your file is really big better chunk it.

Answer (score 4):

It is simple, you are trying to buffer too much data.

This is your culprit:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
```

Since your data source is JSON, you can simply use `JsonReader` to parse your data source piece by piece. This way you can read all the data without having it *all* stored in memory at the same time.

There is an example for using [JsonReader in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html).

In your case you would initialize it like this:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Large heap is a bad solution. Instead use [Gson Streaming](http://www.mkyong.com/java/gson-streaming-to-read-and-write-json/) or [Jackson](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_streaming_api.htm). Or you can also use @knossos answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing Json also put into doInbackgroud() mehod